# How to prevent parallel Sidekiq jobs from executing code in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, multithreading, sidekiq, rails-activejob

I have around 10 workers that performs a job that includes the following:

```
user = User.find_or_initialize_by(email: 'some-email@address.com')

if user.new_record?
# ... some code here that does something taking around 5 seconds or so
elsif user.persisted?
# ... some code here that does something taking around 5 seconds or so
end

user.save
```

The problem is that at certain times, two or more workers run this code at the exact time, and thus I later found out that two or more Users have the same `email`, in which I should always end up only unique emails.

It is not possible for my situation to create DB Unique Indexes for `email` as unique emails are conditional -- some Users should have unique email, some do not.

It is noteworthy to mention that my `User` model has uniqueness validations, but it still doesn't help me because, between `.find_or_initialize_by` and `.save`, there is a code that is dependent if the user object is already created or not.

I tried Pessimistic and Optimistic locking, but it didn't help me, or maybe I just didn't implement it properly... should you have some suggestions regarding this.

The solution I can only think of is to lock the other threads (Sidekiq jobs) whenever these lines of codes get executed, but I am not too sure how to implement this nor do I  know if this is even a suggestable approach.

I would appreciate any help.

EDIT

In my specific case, it is gonna be hard to put email parameter in the job, as this job is a little more complex than what was just said above. The job is actually an export script in which a section of the job is the code above. I don't think it's also possible to separate the functionality above into another separate worker... as the whole job flow should be serial and that no parts should be processed parallely / asynchronously. This job is just one of the jobs that are managed by another job, in which ultimately is managed by the master job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve my problem with the following:

I found out that I can actually add a `where` clause in [Rails DB Uniqueness Partial Index](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements/add_index), and thus I can now set up uniqueness conditions for different types of Users on the database-level in which other concurrent jobs will now raise an `ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique` error if already created.

The only problem now then is the code in between `.find_or_initialize_by` and `.save`, since those are time-dependent on the User objects in which always only one concurrent job should always get a `.new_record? == true`, and other concurrent jobs should then trigger the `.persisted? == true` as one job would always be first to create it, but... all of these doesn't work yet because it is only at the line `.save` where the db uniqueness index validation gets called. Therefore, I managed to solve this problem by putting `.save` before those conditions, and at the same time I added a rescue block for `.save` which then adds another job to the queue of itself should it trigger the `ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique` error, to make sure that async jobs won't get conflicts. The code now looks like below.

```
user = User.find_or_initialize_by(email: 'some-email@address.com')

begin
  user.save
  is_new_record = user.new_record?
  is_persisted = user.persisted?

rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique => exception
  MyJob.perform_later(params_hash)
end

if is_new_record
  # do something if not yet created
elsif is_persisted
  # do something if already created
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Pessimistic locking is what you want but only works on a record that exists - you can't use it with `new_record?` because there's nothing to lock in the DB yet.

Comment: Yeah, that was my problem earlier as well when I was trying Pessimistic locking -- the record still wasn't there. Well, this is still quite unfamiliar to me, so I just thought that maybe I did something wrong in how I approached it. But I guess, I'll go try with pessimistic locking again and maybe find a thread locking hack along with it. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest a different architecture to bypass the problem.

How about a producer-worker model, where one master Sidekiq process gets a list of email addresses, and then spawns a worker Sidekiq process for each email? Sidekiq makes this easy with a dedicated queue for master and workers to communicate.

Doing so, the email address becomes an input parameter of workers, so we know *by construction* that workers will not stump on each other data.

Comment: There was another answer here, but he deleted it. I mentioned there that in my specific case, it is gonna be hard to put email parameter in the job, as this job is a little more complex than what was just said above. The job is actually an export script in which a section of the job is the code above.  I don't think it's also possible to separate the functionality above into another separate worker... as the whole job flow should be serial and that no parts should be processed parallely / asynchronously. I do appreciate your gesture though. Thanks.

Comment: I see. How do you think of making your question a bit narrower, then? Adding the detail of your comment would make the whole thread more useful to people who face similar issues. I do not know about your exact situation, but (in general) it may be worth trying to break down the task into short pieces (recommended by Mike Perham---creator of Sidekiq). Overall it seems you need transactional processing. That is a bit more work, but a master process could manage a transaction for its workers, too...

Comment: I initially thought of simplifying my question, but I guess you're right, I will update my question to include the specifics. Yes, we're currently implementing transactional processing, and have a lot of independent jobs actually (one of which includes this one). However, I think I am beginning to now understand what you meant of a master process specifically when you mentioned 'manage a transaction for its workers'. I will discuss the prospect to my colleagues. Thanks again.